# Props added to component are not available in the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blitz.js

I have a component called `DashboardLayout`, with prop definitions inferred from an interface `LayoutProps`.
When I add new props to `LayoutProps`, they don't show up in either a) the props variable or b) the dev tools. console.log-ing all keys of props show all previous props, but no new ones.

Adding new props to other components works.

Here is a minimal code example:

```
interface LayoutProps {
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  sitemapLinks?: SitemapLink[];
  translateTitle?: boolean;
  modul?: ModuleBase;
}

const DashboardLayout: BlitzLayout<LayoutProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
      <UnsuspendedLayout {...props} />
      <ReactTooltip />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

```
const adminModule = new AdministrationModule();

Admin.getLayout = (page) => (
  <DashboardLayout
    sitemapLinks={adminModule.generateSitemapLinks()}
    slug={adminModule.name}
    title={adminModule.title}
    modul={adminModule}
  >
    {page}
  </DashboardLayout>
);
```

The prop in question would be `mod`.

Comment: logging the `props` will show you the actual props you pass to the component, not the ones supported by the component. How do you use the `DashboardLayout` ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I have a `BlitzPage` component. I've added an example to my question

Comment: So, your interface declares a `mod` but in your code you are passing a `modul` property.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying around with renaming the prop and copy-pasted wrong. I adjusted it to how it looks right now in my code base